# How to send a 2D Nav goal without the button "2D Nav Goal" in RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS developers,

I would like to send a nav goal to move my robot to the specific destination without the button "2D Nav Goal" in RVIZ. Do you have some clues for me to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance! I appreciate your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393921/how-to-send-a-2d-nav-goal-without-the-button-%222d-nav-goal%22-in-rviz?/) by [sincoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/91214/sincoy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You want to create a `SimpleActionClient`. Here is a link to a tutorial that uses roscpp:

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @sincoy

There is a great answer that will help you get started.
https://answers.ros.org/question/252236/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-give-a-robot-a-predefined-set-of-waypoints/

From there you may have a more specific answer on how to.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ros 2 which I recommend if you aren't, then you can use the [Simple Commander API](https://navigation.ros.org/commander_api/index.html) for Python. It can send a single goal and get feedback about its progress or multiple goals at once.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my case, when I set 2d nav goal in `rviz`, the message topic name is:

```
/move_base_simple/goal
```

and the message type is:

```
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped
```